# Create A New bootstrap column when repeater fields contain more than 6 values

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am Trying to build A Restaurant Menu With ACF Repeater Fields and a custom post type the title of the custom post type tells the category for example BBQ and the repeater_fields shows the menu items The issue is that I want to create a new bootstrap column when li reach 6 items in the loop.

```
<div class="fadeIn col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" >
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'menu'));
    if($loop->have_posts()) :
        $i=0;
        ?>
        <div class="row">
    <?php while($loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post(); ?> 
<ul style="width:50%" class="menu-list col-md-6 column  <?php echo the_title(); ?>">
        <?php while(the_repeater_field('item')):  ?>
        <li style="max-width:1000px;"><strong class="icon">&#x2022;</strong>&nbsp;<b><?php the_sub_field('heading'); ?></b><span class="price" >1.95</span><br><strong style="font-weight:400;margin-left:22px;">Soybean paste broth</strong></li>
        <?php  endwhile;?>  
    </ul>
 <?php endwhile;  endif; ?>
</div>

</div>
```

I want to automatically create a new col-md-6 ul if items in the li exceed 5 items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this can work?

```
    <div class="fadeIn col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" >
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'menu'));
    if($loop->have_posts()) :
        $i=0;
        ?>
        <div class="row">

    <?php while($loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $i = 0; ?>
        <ul style="width:50%" class="menu-list col-md-6 column  <?php echo the_title(); ?>">
        <?php while(the_repeater_field('item')):  ?>
        <?php ++$i; ?>
        <?php if($i % 6 == 0): ?>
         </ul>
         <ul style="width:50%" class="menu-list col-md-6 column  <?php echo the_title(); ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>     
        <li style="max-width:1000px;"><strong class="icon">&#x2022;</strong>&nbsp;<b><?php the_sub_field('heading'); ?></b><span class="price" >1.95</span><br><strong style="font-weight:400;margin-left:22px;">Soybean paste broth</strong></li>

        <?php  endwhile;?>  
    </ul>
 <?php endwhile;  endif; ?>
</div>

</div>
```

EDIT: Since I cant yet comment...The approved answer posted by @Bas Mulder is not going to work, if you have more than 12 entries:

```
<div class="row">
        <?php while($loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $j = 0; ?>
        <ul style="width:50%" class="menu-list col-md-6 column  <?php echo the_title(); ?>">
            <?php while(the_repeater_field('item')):  ?>
                <?php if ($j === 5): ?>
                    </ul><ul style="width:50%" class="menu-list col-md-6 column  <?php echo the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php $j = 0; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <li style="max-width:1000px;"><strong class="icon">&#x2022;</strong>&nbsp;<b><?php the_sub_field('heading'); ?></b><span class="price" >1.95</span><br><strong style="font-weight:400;margin-left:22px;">Soybean paste broth</strong></li>
                <?php $j++; ?>
            <?php  endwhile;?>
            </ul>
        <?php endwhile;  endif; ?>
    </div>
```

As second time, it will create new UL on 5 entries. As once new UL is created, j is set to 0 and instantly increased to 1, so once your code hits the 11 element, new UL will be created.

EDIT 2: Due to issue, I updated my answer, so initial

```
$i++;
```

was changed to

```
++$i;
```

Second solution would be to move $i++; below if:

```
   <?php if($i % 6 == 0): ?>
   <?php ++$i; ?>
```

Comment: Yeah I bet you are correct that isn't working in more than 12 entries

Comment: It work although there's a bug let's say i have 14 entries then it will show 5 entries in the first ul then 6 in the second and 3 in the last one i want it to show 6 entries in the first and second and then the remaining 2 in the last ul

Comment: Try my solution, should work. Also, if you change $i % 6 == 0 to  like 7 or 8, it should create 7 or 8 li elements before creating new ul. Please report if this is working for you.

Comment: Yup...I saw it now. Updated original answer, tested (only PHP part) and it works

Comment: Hey just a question instead of 6 i actually want this code to work :     
   $my_fields = get_field_object('item');
  $count = count(($my_fields['value']));
 $show = ceil($count/2); i want to fetch total values and show half half on 2 ul's

Comment: If I understand, you would like to show something like 7 in one ul and 7 in second ul, or 6-6 or whatever? Ok, I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="fadeIn col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12" >
    <?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'menu'));
    if($loop->have_posts()) :
    $i=0;
    ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php while($loop->have_posts() ): $loop->the_post(); ?>
            <?php $j = 0; ?>
        <ul style="width:50%" class="menu-list col-md-6 column  <?php echo the_title(); ?>">
            <?php while(the_repeater_field('item')):  ?>
                <?php if ($j === 5): ?>
                    </ul><ul style="width:50%" class="menu-list col-md-6 column  <?php echo the_title(); ?>">
                    <?php $j = 0; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <li style="max-width:1000px;"><strong class="icon">&#x2022;</strong>&nbsp;<b><?php the_sub_field('heading'); ?></b><span class="price" >1.95</span><br><strong style="font-weight:400;margin-left:22px;">Soybean paste broth</strong></li>
                <?php $j++; ?>
            <?php  endwhile;?>
            </ul>
        <?php endwhile;  endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But Not for entries above 12

Comment: Yes you are right. Change <?php if ($j === 5): ?> to <?php if ($j === 6): ?> and it will work correctly

Answer (score 0):

I am adding another answer, since its not directly related to original question.
Based on the comment, to have two uls with li elements, you could do it like this:

```
$my_fields = get_field_object('item'); 
$count = count(($my_fields['value'])); 
$showFirst = ceil($count/2);
$showSecond = $count - $showFirst;
```

Than you do something like:

```
<?php $show = $showFirst; ?>

 <ul style="width:50%" class="menu-list col-md-6 column  <?php echo the_title(); ?>">
 <?php for($i = 0; $i < $show; $i++):  ?>
    <li style="max-width:1000px;">
        <strong class="icon">&#x2022;</strong>&nbsp;<b><?php the_sub_field('heading'); ?></b><span class="price" >1.95</span><br><strong style="font-weight:400;margin-left:22px;">Soybean paste broth</strong>
    </li>
 <?php if($i == ($show - 1)): ?>
 </ul>
 <ul style="width:50%" class="menu-list col-md-6 column  <?php echo the_title(); ?>">
    $i = 0;
    $show = $showSecond;
<?php endif; ?> 
<?php  end for;?>
```